# Jasper Report Print for LQ300+II

Tags: printing, jasper-reports, dot-matrix

I need to create a Jasper Report for report for the size of 6' x 4' which is feed using tractor as continuous paper. My report is printed successfully for 1st page.But second page is printed very close to the tear mark. 3 page is started to print from end of second page.

My page size in Jasper is 6'x4'
Page margins are 0.278' from all sides.

Answer (score 1):

Define your paper size (User defined paper tab) in Printing Preferences, and also set that defined name under Advanced Option, paper size.

Comment: I already did it.But still prints successfully for 1st page.But second page is printed very close to the tear mark. 3 page is started to print from end of second page